# Get internal Memory size free/total/Available

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, memory

Hello i'm try to get device total and free internal memory size using below method. but its returning me wrong values:

```
 fun totalMemory(): Long {
    val statFs = StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().absolutePath)
    return (statFs.blockCount * statFs.blockSize).toLong()
}

fun freeMemory(): Long {
    val statFs = StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().absolutePath)
    return (statFs.availableBlocks * statFs.blockSize).toLong()
}

fun busyMemory(): Long {
    val statFs = StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().absolutePath)
    val total = (statFs.blockCount * statFs.blockSize).toLong()
    val free = (statFs.availableBlocks * statFs.blockSize).toLong()
    return total - free
}
```

i'm using below method to convert values in human readable form:

```
fun floatForm(d: Double): String {
    return DecimalFormat("#.##").format(d)
}


fun bytesToHuman(size: Long): String? {
    val Kb = 1 * 1024.toLong()
    val Mb = Kb * 1024
    val Gb = Mb * 1024
    val Tb = Gb * 1024
    val Pb = Tb * 1024
    val Eb = Pb * 1024
    if (size < Kb) return floatForm(size.toDouble()) + " byte"
    if (size >= Kb && size < Mb) return floatForm(size.toDouble() / Kb) + " Kb"
    if (size >= Mb && size < Gb) return floatForm(size.toDouble() / Mb) + " Mb"
    if (size >= Gb && size < Tb) return floatForm(size.toDouble() / Gb) + " Gb"
    if (size >= Tb && size < Pb) return floatForm(size.toDouble() / Tb) + " Tb"
    if (size >= Pb && size < Eb) return floatForm(size.toDouble() / Pb) + " Pb"
    return if (size >= Eb) floatForm(size.toDouble() / Eb) + " Eb" else "???"
}
```

i need to get the actual free/total internal size.

Comment: You should include what your code returns and what you expect it to return. That probably makes helping you faster

Comment: this method return me *totalMemory : -1751187456 byte
    freeMemory : 49.44 Mb*

Comment: in file manager is show actual total size is 32GB and free space is 13.8 GB